# How to concat two integer variables to form a long variable

Tags: java

I have a long type variable which should be saved to a byte buffer. Since in Java all int values are fit into 4 bytes and all long values are stored in 8 bytes, and I have access to a simple functionality which saves integers in 4 bytes, I came up with this solution:

```
public class TestApp {

    static byte [] buffer = new byte[8];

    static public void writeInt(int startIndex, int number) {
        buffer[startIndex]     = (byte) (number >> 24);
        buffer[startIndex + 1] = (byte) (number >> 16 & 0x000000FF);
        buffer[startIndex + 2] = (byte) (number >>  8 & 0x000000FF);
        buffer[startIndex + 3] = (byte) (number & 0x000000FF);
    }

    static public int readInt(int startIndex) {
        return
            (buffer[startIndex] & 0xFF) << 24 |
            (buffer[startIndex+1] & 0xFF) << 16 |
            (buffer[startIndex+2] & 0xFF) << 8 |
            (buffer[startIndex+3] & 0xFF);
    }

    static public void writeLong(int startIndex, long number) {
        writeInt(startIndex, (int)(number >> 32));
        writeInt(startIndex + 4, (int)number);
    }

    static public long readLong(int startIndex) {
        long a1 = readInt(startIndex);
        long a2 = readInt(startIndex+4);
        long b= a1 << 32;
        b |= a2;
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        long r = 817859255185602L;

        writeLong(0, r);
        long test = readLong(0);

        System.out.println(Long.toString(r));
        System.out.println(Long.toString(test));
    }
}
```

It was astonishing to see that `readLong()` actually fails to do what it's supposed to do. What I thought when writing the `readLong()` and `writeLong()` was that when shifting one Integer value 32 bits leftwise, and or-ing the result with the next integer; the result would become the desired long value. But this sample proved me wrong. What is wrong with or-ing two Integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in this part:

```
long a1 = readInt(startIndex);
long a2 = readInt(startIndex+4);
```

`readInt` returns an `int`. This is converted to long automatically. Conversion to long doesn't simply add four bytes of zeros. It extends the sign bit to the left.

In this case, `a2` was `0xb261b0c2`. This means its most significant bit - the sign bit - is 1. So it was extended to the long `0xffffffffb261b0c2`.

Of course, when you OR that with the shifted `a1`, the result will always be `0xffffffff________`.

What you should do is

```
long a2 = readInt(startIndex+4) & 0xffffffffL;
```

This will ensure that the most significant four bytes of `a2` will remain zero, and thus be neutral when you OR them with the shifted `a1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the sign bit. I had neglected its significance.

Answer (score 0):

RealSkeptic's answer is correct. It seems to me that you are trying to reinvent the wheel, though. E.g. [Guava](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html) already has conversions between long/int/... and byte arrays:

```
    long r = 817859255185602L;
    byte[] buffer = Longs.toByteArray(r);
    long test = Longs.fromByteArray(buffer);
```